# Too much white space around column!

Tags: spacing, two-column, multicolumn, exam

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pts]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol, setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp, booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
OPD ENCOUNTER FORM}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}
    \section{History}

        \begin{questions}

        \question Patient was symptomatic since \hrulefill . 
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{checkboxes}
        \choice Abdominal pain \hrulefill 
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice  hypochondriac / epigastric / periumbilical / iliac fossa / diffuse 
        \choice  Left /right 
        \choice  Burn /dull ache / cramp/ colic
        \choice  Radiates to \hrulefill 
        \choice  Related to meals/ motions/ micturition/ menses/ movement/ None 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
        \choice Loss of  appetite \hrulefill
        \choice Belching \hrulefill
        \choice Regurgitation of sour fluid in mouth \hrulefill
        \choice Heart burn \hrulefill
        \choice Dysphagia \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Intermittent
        \choice Progressive 
        \choice Painful 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
        \choice Vomitings \hrulefill
        \choice Dyspepsia  \hrulefill 
        \choice Hematemesis \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Melena \choice hemodynamic unstability \choice endoscopy done \choice blood/products received \hrulefill
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
        \choice Bloating of abdomen
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Minor \choice significant 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 

        \choice Altered bowel habits \hrulefill 
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Constipation

        \choice diarrhea 
        \choice Frequency \hrulefill  \choice Bristol scale type \hrulefill \choice Bleeding  
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Separate \choice Mixed 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
        \choice Nonsatisfactory defecation with repeated visits to toilet 
        \choice Prolonged toilet time 
        \choice straining 
        \choice tenesmus 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Flatulence 
        \choice Jaundice \hrulefill 
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Fluctuating \choice Worsening \choice better 
        \choice Prodrome present \choice cholestatic symptoms 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
        \choice Distended abdomen \hrulefill 
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice generalised \choice localised \choice progressively Worsening \choice better \choice tapped fluid \hrulefill \choice swelling over feet \choice Urine output 
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Adequate \choice Reduced 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
        \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
    \choice Altered behaviour \hrulefill 
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice worsening \choice fluctuating \choice better \choice focal weakness \hrulefill \choice seizures  \hrulefill 
    \end{oneparcheckboxes} 
    \choice Urinary symptoms 
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Reduced urine output \choice Dysuria \choice hematuria 
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Menstrual abnormality (female) \hrulefill 
    \end{checkboxes} \end{multicols} 
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This code compiles to ...

[image: compiled image]

Have a look at the white space on either side of columns. How can I optimize it? To me, it looks excessive !

Comment: You set `\setlength\columnsep{40pt}` on line 5 so you get 40pt of space between the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set

```
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
```

on line 5 so you get 40pt of space between the columns

Answer (score 1):

You have a `\checkboxeshook` command that allows to modify the list parameters used by the `checkboxes` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pts]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol, setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp, booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand\checkboxeshook{\setlength\leftmargin{0cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
OPD ENCOUNTER FORM}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}
    \section{History}

        \begin{questions}

        \question Patient was symptomatic since \hrulefill .
  \begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{checkboxes}\uplevel
         \choice Abdominal pain \hrulefill

\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice hypochondriac / epigastric / periumbilical / iliac fossa / diffuse
        \choice Left /right
        \choice Burn /dull ache / cramp/ colic
        \choice Radiates to \hrulefill
        \choice Related to meals/ motions/ micturition/ menses/ movement/ None
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Loss of appetite \hrulefill
        \choice Belching \hrulefill
        \choice Regurgitation of sour fluid in mouth \hrulefill
        \choice Heart burn \hrulefill
        \choice Dysphagia \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Intermittent
        \choice Progressive
        \choice Painful
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Vomitings \hrulefill
        \choice Dyspepsia \hrulefill
        \choice Hematemesis \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Melena \choice hemodynamic unstability \choice endoscopy done \choice blood/products received \hrulefill
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Bloating of abdomen
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Minor \choice significant
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}

        \choice Altered bowel habits \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Constipation

        \choice diarrhea
        \choice Frequency \hrulefill \choice Bristol scale type \hrulefill \choice Bleeding
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Separate \choice Mixed
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Nonsatisfactory defecation with repeated visits to toilet
        \choice Prolonged toilet time
        \choice straining
        \choice tenesmus
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Flatulence
        \choice Jaundice \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Fluctuating \choice Worsening \choice better
        \choice Prodrome present \choice cholestatic symptoms
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Distended abdomen \hrulefill
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice generalised \choice localised \choice progressively Worsening \choice better \choice tapped fluid \hrulefill \choice swelling over feet \choice Urine output
        \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Adequate \choice Reduced
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
        \end{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Altered behaviour \hrulefill
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice worsening \choice fluctuating \choice better \choice focal weakness \hrulefill \choice seizures \hrulefill
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Urinary symptoms
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Reduced urine output \choice Dysuria \choice hematuria
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Menstrual abnormality (female) \hrulefill
    \end{checkboxes}
 \end{multicols}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]